# Tensorflow object detection api - get accuracy and loss for both train and eval datasets

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I have been training an object detection model with tensorflow object detection api. I have questions regarding the ways to evaluate the quality of the model.

On tensorboard, I can display the loss accross the steps for the train dataset but not for the eval dataset. Also I can only check the accuracy (mAP) at the very final stage of the training process. My question is: **is there a way to  visualize the evolution of accuracy and loss for both the train and the eval datasets while training?**

I have tried different solution: use model_main.py instead of model_main_tf2.py, run eval.py and train.py as suggested below but it gave me errors.

 [Tensorflow Object Detection API only shows loss value. How to get mAP value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140300/tensorflow-object-detection-api-only-shows-loss-value-how-to-get-map-value)

It is possible these options are merely not available yet with tf2 object detection api:

 [How to train and eval at the same time in Tensorflow Object Detection API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63909232/how-to-train-and-eval-at-the-same-time-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api-v2)

model = ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8

python = 3.8.5

tensorflow = 2.4.1